# How to track down the cause of "syntax error: missing ')' before identifier" and others?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, syntax

Im writing a project in C with visual studio that contains these files:

1. multiThreadServer.cpp
2. myLib.cpp
3. myLib.h

The 1st (multiThreadServer.cpp) includes these

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myLib.h"
```

2nd (myLib.cpp) these

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "myLib.h"
```

3nd (myLib.h) includes nothing

In .h file i have these functions defined:

```
// Starts up the server.
INT start_server(const unsigned short port);
// Accept Connections.
BOOL accept_connections();
// Accept Client.
BOOL AcceptClient(PCLIENT current_client);
// Receiver Function for the thread.
DWORD WINAPI Receiver(LPVOID lpParam);
// Receive data from client.
BOOL recv_data(PCLIENT current_client, char *buffer, int size);
// End server.
VOID end_server();
// Send data.
BOOL send_data(PCLIENT current_client, char *buffer, int size);
// Disconnect Client.
VOID disconnect_client(PCLIENT current_client);
// Send Data to all clients.
BOOL send_data_to_all(char *message);
```

Here is part of myLib.cpp:

```
typedef struct _client{
    SOCKADDR_IN     address;        // internal data structure regarding this client
    SOCKET          socket;         // this clients socket
    BOOL            connected;      // is this client connected
    char            IP[20];         // this clients IP address
    int             address_length; // internal data structure regarding this client
} CLIENT, *PCLIENT;
```

Now, when im going to compile the whole project these annoying syntax errors returned:

```
1>  myLib.cpp
\mylib.h(8): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(8): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(8): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
\mylib.h(14): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(14): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(14): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(14): error C2059: syntax error : ','
\mylib.h(14): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
\mylib.h(20): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(20): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(20): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(20): error C2059: syntax error : ','
\mylib.h(20): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
\mylib.h(23): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(23): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(23): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
\mylib.cpp(103): warning C4013: 'AcceptClient' undefined; assuming extern returning int
\mylib.cpp(168): warning C4013: 'recv_data' undefined; assuming extern returning int
\mylib.cpp(188): warning C4013: 'send_data' undefined; assuming extern returning int
\mylib.cpp(189): warning C4013: 'disconnect_client' undefined; assuming extern returning int
\mylib.cpp(270): error C2371: 'disconnect_client' : redefinition; different basic types
1>  multiThreadServer.cpp
\mylib.h(8): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
1\mylib.h(8): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(8): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(8): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
\mylib.h(14): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(14): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(14): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(14): error C2059: syntax error : ','
\mylib.h(14): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
\mylib.h(20): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(20): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(20): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(20): error C2059: syntax error : ','
\mylib.h(20): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
\mylib.h(23): error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'current_client'
\mylib.h(23): error C2059: syntax error : ';'
\mylib.h(23): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I m searching 1.30 hour now on net but i cannot find a way to fix it.

What the problem could be ?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't know what PCLIENT is.

Comment: In this http://pastebin.com/vmM63jX2 structure which is in myLib.cpp

Comment: @F.N : In the future, please put the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8421566/968261), you fix the problem in the header file without actually moving the definition of `PCLIENT` into the header:

```
...
struct _client;
...
// Accept Client.
BOOL AcceptClient(struct _client* current_client);
...
// Receive data from client.
BOOL recv_data(struct _client* current_client, char *buffer, int size);
...
// Send data.
BOOL send_data(struct _client* current_client, char *buffer, int size);
// Disconnect Client.
VOID disconnect_client(struct _client* current_client);
...
```

Comment: @AJG85 Thank you for your explanation and sorry once again for the codes. Alex Thank you too. Now compilation works.